# Delete multiple xml nodes with same name (but not all)

Tags: xml, oracle10g

How can I delete an xml node based on the data within.

For example if in the below I wanted to ONLY delete these two

```
     <MMGroupID>143</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>70</MMGroupID>  

<Promotion>
 <LastUpdated>2012-08-03T12:15:24+01:00</LastUpdated>
 <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
 <MinorVersion>7</MinorVersion>
 <MultibuyGroup>
     <XMLSchemaVersion>1</XMLSchemaVersion>
     <UseLowestNetValue>0</UseLowestNetValue>
     <MMGroupID>975</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>41</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>143</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>70</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>36</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>22</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>870</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>90</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>88</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>142</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>147</MMGroupID>
     <TriggerOnLostSales>0</TriggerOnLostSales>
 </MultibuyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`deleteXML()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB4305) with an XPath that specifies the node values you want:

```
deleteXml(<your_xml>, q'{//MMGroupID[text()='143' or text()='70']}')
```

Demo:

```
select XMLSerialize(document
  deleteXML(XMLType(
'<Promotion>
 <LastUpdated>2012-08-03T12:15:24+01:00</LastUpdated>
 <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
 <MinorVersion>7</MinorVersion>
 <MultibuyGroup>
     <XMLSchemaVersion>1</XMLSchemaVersion>
     <UseLowestNetValue>0</UseLowestNetValue>
     <MMGroupID>975</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>41</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>143</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>70</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>36</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>22</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>870</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>90</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>88</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>142</MMGroupID>
     <MMGroupID>147</MMGroupID>
     <TriggerOnLostSales>0</TriggerOnLostSales>
 </MultibuyGroup>
</Promotion>'),
  q'{//MMGroupID[text()='143' or text()='70']}')
  as CLOB INDENT size = 2)
from dual;
```

which produces:

```
XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTDELETEXML(XMLTYPE('<PROMOTION><LASTUPDATED>2012-08-03T12:15
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Promotion>
  <LastUpdated>2012-08-03T12:15:24+01:00</LastUpdated>
  <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
  <MinorVersion>7</MinorVersion>
  <MultibuyGroup>
    <XMLSchemaVersion>1</XMLSchemaVersion>
    <UseLowestNetValue>0</UseLowestNetValue>
    <MMGroupID>975</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>41</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>36</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>22</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>870</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>90</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>88</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>142</MMGroupID>
    <MMGroupID>147</MMGroupID>
    <TriggerOnLostSales>0</TriggerOnLostSales>
  </MultibuyGroup>
</Promotion>
```